# Change color of a drawing in canvas after loop ends

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on an assignment I got and I can't find a solution.
It's a js canvas drawing of a ball that goes from left to right and once it reaches a specific x-coordinates starts again from the left, over and over.
I want to make it go from yellow to blue alternatively once it starts its cycle again. This is my code:

```
/* --- HTML --- */

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>CANVAS</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="contenido">

<section id="tres">
    <p>3</p>
    <canvas id="lienzoTres" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</section>

</body>
</html>

/* --- JS --- */

function animar() {
    var elemento=document.getElementById('lienzoTres');
    lienzo3=elemento.getContext('2d');
    x=70;
    y=130;
    radio=70;
    lienzo3.fillStyle="yellow";
    intervalo=setInterval(circuloAmarillo, 5);
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", animar, false);

function circuloAmarillo(){
    lienzo3.clearRect(x - radio, y - radio, radio * 2, radio * 2);
    x++;
    lienzo3.beginPath();
    lienzo3.arc(x,y,radio,0,Math.PI*2, false);
    lienzo3.fill();
    if(x>=430){
    lienzo3.clearRect(0, 0, 550, 300);
    x=70;
    cambiacolor();
    } 
}

function cambiacolor() {
    if (lienzo3.fillStyle=="yellow") {
    lienzo3.fillStyle="blue";
    } else if (lienzo3.fillStyle=="blue") {
    lienzo3.fillStyle="yellow";
    }
}
```

I dind't include css because it doesn't seem to be the problem.
Any thoughts on how I can make it switch from yellow to blue every time it completes a left-to-right run?

Thanks!

Comment: becasue `fillStyle` only store RGB color, not a represent string, so your color will never equal, you can jsut set lienzo3.fillStyle="blue" while you call `cambiacolor` function

Comment: Thank you very much! I had some suspicion on that when I logged lienzo3.fillStyle and it returned #ffff00 but couldn't go further. Changing everything from those misleading color names to hex fixed it. I thought I had already learned the 'data types' lesson... my bad.

Comment: Thanks again, It was my first question here and you were really kind to me. You helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anami has pointed out, you have to change your `cambiacolor` method as below

```js
function cambiacolor() {
  if (lienzo3.fillStyle == "#ffff00") {
    lienzo3.fillStyle = "blue";
  } else if (lienzo3.fillStyle == "#0000ff") {
    lienzo3.fillStyle = "yellow";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What a kind community here. I'm really happy to have reached you.